# No OpenCV script working on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: python, pi-3, opencv

I had written few python scripts on Windows using opencv 3.2.0 and python 2.7.13. I, then, installed the same version of opencv on my R-Pi, and tried running the very same scripts on it, but none of themm work. I am posting the simplest of the scripts here

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('Photos\WIN_20170102_20_34_33_Pro.jpg', 0)
img = cv2.medianBlur(img, 5)
cv2.imshow('Veins', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/pi/Desktop/Basic Project codes/hist.py", line 8, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('Veins', img)
error: /home/pi/opencv-3.2.0/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:304: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

Other codes also return various errors.
What can be the possible problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use in python`os.path.join("Photos", "WIN_20170102_20_34_33_Pro.jpg")` to join the path of a file OS-independent.
The error might be because the image has no size when you are trying to show it.